# reusing user controls in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

i'm relatively new to wpf/mvvm so this is probably something basic, but I have a user control that displays perfectly on its own, but when I try to load it into a stackpanel of a different user control, it won't display at all. does anyone have any idea of what i'm doing incorrectly here? i've tried setting up the width/height/minwidth/minheight, but none of it makes a difference.

here is the xaml for the re-usable user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BankProductControlLibrary.Views.IdentificationData"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:bpcl="clr-namespace:BankProductControlLibrary.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="102" d:DesignWidth="535">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/BankProductSilverlightControl;component/Resources/Style.xaml"/>

                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="textBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="409" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="textBlockStyle2" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="comboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="180" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="132" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="dateBoxStyle" TargetType="bpcl:DateBox">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="dateFormatingExplanationStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="(mm/dd/yyyy)" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="placeOfIssuanceExplanationStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    </Style>                    

                </ResourceDictionary>

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel MinHeight="102" MinWidth="535">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">
               Select the ID provided from the drop-down list.  ID must be a photo ID.
        </TextBlock>

        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ScreenStyle}" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="88*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="142*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Column0-->
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle2}"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Type:"                    
                   />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle2}"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Date of Issuance:" 
                   />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle2}"
                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Place of Issuance:" />

            <!--Column1-->
            <ComboBox Name="Ids" Style="{StaticResource comboBoxStyle}"    
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value"
            SelectedValuePath="Key"                      
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTaxpayerId, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <bpcl:DateBox x:Name="IssueDate" Style="{StaticResource dateBoxStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource dateFormatingExplanationStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <!--This should be bpcl:AlphaTextBox-->
                <TextBox Name="PlaceOfIssuance" Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}" 
                    MaxLength="2"
                    Width="40"/>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource placeOfIssuanceExplanationStyle}"                               
                        Text="Enter state abbreviation or country code"    

                        />
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Column2-->
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle2}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                    Text="ID Number:"        
                    />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle2}"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                    Text="Expiration Date:"/>

            <!--Column3-->
            <TextBox Name="IdentificationNumber" Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}" 
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" >
                <bpcl:DateBox x:Name="ExpirationDate" Style="{StaticResource dateBoxStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource dateFormatingExplanationStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and here is where i try to consume it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BankProductControlLibrary.Views.JTH.TaxpayerIdentificationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ltsa="http://www.libtax.com/LibTax/BankApp"
    xmlns:bpcl="clr-namespace:BankProductControlLibrary.UserControls"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BankProductControlLibrary.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d ltsa"
    d:DesignHeight="102" d:DesignWidth="520">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="validationStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <views:IdentificationData x:Name="TPIdentification" />
        <TextBlock Name="ValidationErrorMessage" Style="{StaticResource validationStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I tested your code by removing the references to unknown styles and it worked fine.  It's not an error in any code you've posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check if the user control has datacontext. There is a nice tool that helped me a lot with WPF:
http://wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html